# configurar wampserver para acesso externo

Tags: wampserver

boa tarde.
pretendo configurar o meu servidor web (wamp) para acesso externo.
o que já fiz:
1-tenho conta noIp configurada;
2-configurei no roteador o encaminhamento da porta para o meu Ip local;
3-tenho a porta 8080 aberta no roteador;
4-wampserver (httpd.conf) porta 8080 (listen);
5-adicionei regra de firewall para a porta 8080 no windows (TCP/UDP);

Feito tudo isto, ao abrir o nome do site do noIp, ele apenas mostra o roteador e não o wamp, como se fosse um clone.

O meu roteador: ZTE ZXHN H108N V.25

Alguma dica de como chegar à pasta www?

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61871/discussion-on-question-by-pedro-configurar-wampserver-para-acesso-externo)

Answer (score 0):

Você tem que configurar o seu roteador para fazer um redirecionamento de portas.

A porta 8080 do IP do Roteador, por exemplo, tens que configurar para a porta 8080 do computador (ID) internamente onde está instalado no servidor wamp (Apache).

Eu não tenho esse roteador, mas encontrei esse link.

https://portforward.com/zte/zxhn-h108n/

Comment: isso já foi feito, mas por alguma razão o router não está a encaminhar para o laptop...